# A problem in the proof of Jordan decomposition theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

How to obtain the red rectangle in the picture?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\nu_1(D) = 0$ and $\nu_1 \ge 0$, we have $\nu_1(E) = \nu_1(E\cap D^c) = \nu_1(E \cap C)$, hence using $\nu_2(C) = 0$ and $\nu_2 \ge 0$
\begin{align*}
  \nu_1(E) &= \nu_1(E \cap C)\\
           &= (\alpha + \nu_2)(E \cap C)\\
           &= \alpha(E\cap C) + \nu_2(E\cap C)\\
           &= \alpha(E\cap C).
\end{align*}
For $\nu_2$ we have analogously 
\begin{align*}
  \nu_2(E) &= \nu_2(E \cap D)\\
           &= (-\alpha + \nu_1)(E \cap D)\\
           &= -\alpha(E\cap D) + \nu_1(E\cap D)\\
           &= -\alpha(E\cap D).
\end{align*}